# dafa frame comparison at the row level in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a two data frame like this

source.show()

```
+---+-------+-----+
|name|  mark1| mark2|
+---+-------+-----+
|    Axx|   70|   75|
|    Vxx|   60|   55|
|    Bxx|   45|   80|
|    Mxx|   80|   99|
|   Sxxx|   70|    5|
+---+-------+-----+--
```

target.show()

```
+---+-------+-----+
|name|  mark1| mark2|
+---+-------+-----+
|    Axx|   80|   75|
|    Vxx|   60|   55|
|    Bxx|   45|   80|
|    Mxx|   80|   99|
|   Sxxx|   70|    5|
|    Axx|   70|   75|
|    Vxx|   60|   55|
|    Bxx|   45|   80|
|    Mxx|   80|   99|
|   Sxxx|   70|    5|
|    Axx|   70|   75
+---+-------+-----+--
```

then I am generating row count for target table. Because target table contains repeated rows.

```
+---+-------+-----+
|name|  mark1| mark2|row_number
+---+-------+-----+
|    Axx|   80|   75| 1
|    Vxx|   60|   55| 1
|    Bxx|   45|   80| 1
|    Mxx|   80|   99| 1
|   Sxxx|   70|    5| 1
|    Axx|   70|   75| 1
|    Vxx|   60|   55| 2
|    Bxx|   45|   80| 2 
|    Mxx|   80|   99| 2
|   Sxxx|   70|    5| 2 
|    Axx|   70|   75  2
+---+-------+-----+--
```

I have another column called version. To maintain repeated rows count. While querying pick up the latest version.
Now I need to compare the first 3 columns in source as well as target. IF it is matches then I need to append the data from the source into target (row wise) and increment the version value by 1.

If the first 3 columns doesn't match then I need to append the data from the source into target and set the version value as 0.

I wrote the logic like this

```
val target1=target.withColumn("version",lit(0))
val target2 = target1.select("name","mark1","mark2","version").withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2").orderBy("name")))
val diff = source.select("name","mark1","mark2").except(target2.select("name","mark1","mark2"))
if  ( diff.count > 0){
  val diff1 = source.select("name","mark1","mark2") == target2.select("name","mark1","mark2")
  if ( diff1 == false ) {
val ver = target2.groupBy("name","mark1","mark2").max("rank")
val common = source.select("name","mark1","mark2").intersect(target2.select("name","mark1","mark2"))
val result = common.join(ver, common("name") === ver("name") && common("mark1") === ver("mark1") && common("mark2") === ver("mark2"), "inner").select(ver("name"),ver("mark1"),ver("mark2"),ver("max(rank)") as "version")
val result2 = source.select("name","mark1","mark2").except(target2.select("name","mark1","mark2")).withColumn("version",lit(0))
val final_result = result.union(result2)
final_result.show()
}
}
```

The problem is whenever same set of rows is coming into source and target I need increment the version number.

Example

Source DF :-

```
+---+-------+-----+
|name|  mark1| mark2|
+---+-------+-----+
|    Axx|   70|   75|
|    Axx|   70|   75|
```

Target DF :-

```
+---+-------+-----+
|name|  mark1| mark2|version
+---+-------+-----+
|    Axx|   80|   75| 3
|    Axx|   80|   75| 4
|    Axx|   80|   75| 5
```

My whole logic is working at dataframe level. I need to do all the comparison at row level or field level then I need to increment the version number for the matched set of rows. Any help will be appreciated to achieve the logic.

Comment: I'd like to help you, but the problem you pose is kind of unclear.
It's hard to reproduce, since the diff of source and target is actually empty in your example (and target is missing an id column or so?)
What is the current output and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi Dont mind about the id column. I had edited now. My expected solution is I want to compare the first 3 column in my dataframe 1 & dataframe 2. If its matches I need to increment the version no also append the data from source to target. If not matches append the data from source to target and set version as 0

Comment: In the above solution I am doing it in dataframe level. I need to compare row by row level.Any help??

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but could you not just outer join the datasets and group by name and do some custom udf on the aggregated data? I don't really get what you mean by dataframe-level vs row-level. 
Maybe I'm to dense, but I'm missing what it is you are actually trying to accomplish. I mean how do  you (logically) get from above datasets (source & target) to the bottom two datasets?  For example Axx|   80|   75 appears only once in the original target, but now has 3 records in 'TargetDf` starting at version 3?